# Sort Joomla / Virtuemart generated address list

Tags: php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I'm trying to make a list generated by Virtuemart 2 to be ordered alphabetically. I found where the list is rendered in a view, but I can't do anything with this code, all I have to work with is this:

```
<?php echo $this->lists['shipTo']; ?>
```

I found this code at

```
components/com_virtuemart/views/user/tmpl/edit_address_addshipto.php
```

I tried using JS but I need a class for the UL that is generated, the UL does not get a class.

Can anybody explain to me how I can get this list to be sorted?